# How to access the HTTP code of a response inside a sinatra error handler?

Tags: ruby, http, sinatra

I used this code in an earlier(1.2.6) version of sinatra

```
error 400..510 do |app|
  do_something_with app.status
end
```

Here `app.status` is the numeric code, i.e. a number between 400 and 510 that will be used in the response.

With a recent (1.3.2) version, this no longer works - `app` is `nil`.  I've looked at the documentation and tried `env['sinatra.error']` but that appears to be `nil` as well.

Is this still possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `response.status`? You can probably call it with just `status` as I believe it's a helper.

Comment: `status` worked fine, thanks! The documentation's "All the helpers are available" didn't sink into my mind, I guess